# rake aborted! Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler"

Tags: ruby, rake, bundler, webistrano

Bundler 1.1.1 doesn't seem to be compatible with rake.

I have no idea what is going on, 
I'm trying to install webistrano and when I ran the following command

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

I got:

> rake aborted! Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
>
> In Gemfile:
>
> ```
> bundler (~> 1.0.10) ruby
> ```
>
> Current Bundler version:
>
> ```
> bundler (1.1.1)
> ```
>
> This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
>   Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

I really don't know what to do from here, I just picked up ruby about two weeks ago and I'm not very familiar with all the different gems, and how they are supposed to work.

Other info

```
> ruby -version
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]

> gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***


actionmailer (3.2.2)
actionpack (3.2.2)
activemodel (3.2.2)
activerecord (3.2.2)
activeresource (3.2.2)
activesupport (3.2.2)
arel (3.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.1)
capistrano (2.11.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
highline (1.6.11)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.3)
json (1.6.5, 1.5.4)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.17.2)
minitest (2.11.3, 2.5.1)
multi_json (1.1.0)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.3.0)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.2)
railties (3.2.2)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12, 3.9.4)
sprockets (2.3.1, 2.1.2)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.32)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might try changing:

```
~> 1.0.10
```

to something less strict to allow for new versions, such as

```
>= 1.0.10
```

Comment: Actually, looking at my current Rails project, I noticed I have no reference to bundler in my Gemfile, so you might also try removing the bundler line completely.

Comment: Sorry for ignorance, but what ~> means? Approximately to 1.0.10 ?

Comment: @confiq I've seen it called the "pessimistic version opertator", the "twiddle waka operator", and the "spermy operator".  It allows minor updates, but not major ones.  So, in this case it would update to 1.0.11 but not 1.1.0; here's a good link on it: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rubys-pessimistic-operator

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
~> 1.0.10
```

to

```
~> 1.1.0
```

to allow your current Bundler gem version (1.1.1) to be used successfully.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is `gem uninstall bundler` 
then `bundle _1.11.2_ install` 
then to check the vergion bundler `run bundle _1.11.2_ -v`
And for sure add the bundler gem to the gemfile `gem 'bundler', '~> 1.11.2'`
then run `bundle update`